# Apache superset 0.23.3 in hdp can't connect to sql server via sqlalchemy url

Tags: sqlalchemy, sql-server-2014, python-3.7, apache-superset, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to connect superset 0.23.3 which is in hdp to sql server 2014(local machine) through sqlalchemy but facing an error regarding no module found. Attachments of my sqlalchemy connection string and error is given below:

[This is the image of my connection string and it is correct as i ran this string in spyder and successfully connected with sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR6AX.png)

[Error i am getting after clicking on test connection button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZIP5.png)

[As it is saying in error no module found but it is already installed in site-packages under C:\Python36\Lib\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MiDG.png)

[Already installed in site-packages folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9l0z.png)

[Connected sql server with python via sqlalchemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv2ME.png)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you in a position to connect to that DB directly in python via sqlAlchemy?

Comment: Yes, It is successfully connected and retreiving records via sqlalchemy using spyder.. pls check image[5] i added recently..

Comment: OK. Great. Are you running superset in your global python environment, or in a virtual one?

Comment: virtual environment (hdp sandbox 2.6.5,windows 10) and (hdp sandbox 3.0,redhat) in which python 2.7 and 3.6 both are installed but everything installs in python2.7 through shell e.g. pip install pymssql

Comment: I meant your python virtual env (venv). When you installed superset, did you create a python virtual environment as recommended, and pip-installed everything in that venv? This would explain why you're not seeing the error when connecting through your global python env, but you're hitting it in superset's env.

Comment: Yes, i have created venv in python directory as well as in hdp shell where superset is installed.